# Can I embed different google+ comment boxes to the same post with different string ids?

Tags: google-plus, blogger

Is it possible to embed different Google+ comment boxes to a post that has different string ids in the url.

For example:

http://www.distressedvolatility.com/p/trending-news.html#3.18771?icx_id=http://www.voanews.com/a/janet-yellen-signals-interest-rate-increase-likely-this-month/3748729.html&showTitle=true

and

http://www.distressedvolatility.com/p/trending-news.html#3.13006?icx_id=28666&showTitle=true

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Google+ comment box shows the comments based on the URL, by default the URL is set via Blogger layout tag (like for example `<data:post.canonicalUrl/>`) so that the comments are linked to a single URL despite the post URL changing in the address bar (like mobile version appending `?m=1` or different ccTLDs Blogger uses). To render different comment boxes based on the URL, you can change the `href` parameter to `window.location.href`. The code for same will look like -

```
<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js' />
<div id='comments'>
</div>
<script>
gapi.comments.render('comments', {
    href: window.location.href,
    width: '590',
    first_party_property: 'BLOGGER',
    view_type: 'FILTERED_POSTMOD'
});
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason it isn't working. I have Google+ comment box in a separate widget, so it's actually hidden on Blogger's settings, but I added a widget with this code: `<div class='cmt_iframe_holder' data-viewtype='FILTERED_POSTMOD' expr:href='data:blog.canonicalUrl'/>` and it showed up.

Comment: continued... So do I change `expr:href='data:blog.canonicalUrl'` to something else? I made it so the script you gave would trigger if it's not an item pg. I just need this to work on one pg. Ex: [link](https://end-times-synapse.blogspot.com/p/trending-news.html#3.14989?icx_id=http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/03/seoul-north-korea-carried-missile-tests-170306035312540.html&showTitle=true) and [link](https://end-times-synapse.blogspot.com/p/trending-news.html#3.14989?icx_id=http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/03/tropical-cyclone-enawo-threatens-madagascar-170305094955816.html&showTitle=true)